# Sleep'ы в C# делают код быстрее

Tags: c#, многопоточность

**Всем добра!**

***Наткнулся на одну очень интересную фичу.***

**Немного предыстории, без которой никак:**

Пишу на C# дипломную программу -- многопоточный эмулятор систем массового обслуживания.
Суть программы: задаём все параметры системы и количество потоков (Thread'ов). Во всех потоках система одинаковая, и она моделируется до бесконечности (пока пользователь не остановит).

Сделал -- всё отлично, но возникла проблема: операционная система (win7 x64) не может их нормально синхронизировать. При большом числе потоков (большим, чем число ядер) некоторые потоки по модельному времени очень сильно обгоняют\отстают от других (причём изначально "тормознутый" поток со временем будет отставать от большинства всё сильнее, а "быстрый" -- убегать всё дальше). А нужно, чтобы время было везде примерно одинаковым -- для наглядности.

Не беда! Написал метод, который притормаживает самые быстрые потоки (считается среднее модельное время по всем потокам -- и притормаживаются те потоки, которые на CONST это среднее время опережают). Синхронизация заработала, всё хорошо.

**А потом началось самое интересное:**

Я решил снизить нагрузку на процессор, и в каждом потоке поставил SLEEP(1) [поспать 1 миллисекунду] раз в 100 итераций -- и сделал эту фичу устанавливаемой пользователем (CheckBox на форме, включающий или выключающий эти SLEEP'ы).

Казалось бы, очевидно, что наличие SLEEP'ов в коде должно снижать скорость его выполнения. И при малом числе потоков (сравнимым с числом ядер, которых в моём i5 4) это действительно так. Но при увеличении числа потоков в 2-3 раза (до ~10) разница пропадает. А при дальнейшем увеличении числа потоков (20, 50, 100) программа начинает работать в разы быстрее, причём на загрузке процессора это никак не отражается. **Наличие SLEEP'ов в коде при большом числе потоков делает код гораздо быстрее!**

Тестировал на ноутбуке (win8\x64\2 ядра) -- результат тот же.

Неужели Win7\Win8 настолько плохо синхронизирует потоки, что за счёт периодических SLEEP'ов в коде они синхронизируются лучше, и программа в итоге выполняется быстрее? Потоки-то все равноправные, ОС должна предоставлять всем равные кванты времени CPU.

В коде никаких ошибок нет, копаюсь в этом уже который месяц -- и безрезультатно.

**Раньше я думал, что всё дело в синхронизации -- но теперь я отключил метод для синхронизации потоков между собой -- и результат получился абсолютно таким же: при наличии SLEEP'ов и большого числа потоков код всё равно работает в 2-5 раз быстрее!**

И теперь я уже вообще ничего не понимаю. Может, вы знаете, в чём тут дело?

P.S. да, я чайник, если что.

**Всем спасибо!**

Comment: > А при дальнейшем увеличении числа потоков (20, 50, 100) программа начинает работать в разы быстрее, причём на загрузке процессора это никак не отражается. Наличие SLEEP'ов в коде при большом числе потоков делает код гораздо быстрее!

так может не слипы делают код быстрее, а наличие дополнительных потоков?

Comment: DreamChild:

Нет, при каждом количестве потоков я динамически включал и отключал SLEEP'ы -- и при большом числе потоков наличие SLEEP'ов делает моделирование в разы быстрее.

Comment: показывайте код (разумеется, не весь), только тогда можно будет говорить об этом более предметно.

Comment: ОС должна предоставлять всем равные кванты времени CPU.

С чего вы решили так? :) Скорее всего в виндах все сложнее. Пробовали код в unix?

Comment: @Scycat, немного не понял Ваше описание.

При отключенной синхронизации (и без Sleep), т.е. когда потоки "разбегаются" у Вас тоже вычисления (общий объем по всем потокам, пока пользователь не остановит) медленнее, чем со sleep-ами?

Или в этом режиме Вы не измеряли, а начали уже введя синхронизацию. И давайте, расскажите подробно как именно синхронизируете. 

--

Скорее всего именно на синхронизации (мьютексы, наверное) Вы производительность и теряете. 

А sleep-ы, по сути переводя систему из preemptive в cooperation multitascing, снижают нагрузку в механизме синхронизации.

Comment: @avp, даже вообще без синхронизации, когда потоки разбегаются, со Sleep'ами всё работает намного быстрее (опять же, только при большом числе потоков). Sleep'ы можно включать и выключать динамически -- чекБоксом на форме прямо во время выполнения, и при этом видно, как включение задержек ускоряет выполнение.

Comment: @Scycat еще раз - если хотите конкретной и предметной помощи в вашем вопросе, а не предположений и домыслов, покажите код, воспроизводящий данное поведение. В противном случае сказать что-то более точное вряд ли представляется  возможным

Comment: @Scycat, Вы еще раз убедительно показали, что **"Threads are Evil"** (особенно в руках молодого бойца).

Если серьезно, то [читать здесь](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2006/EECS-2006-1.pdf), ну и еще в куче мест.

Comment: Почему бы не задуматься об архитектуре и не позволить полодить потоки более чем в два раза больше количество процессоров умноженных наядра? Нужно пора задуматься об очереди и не мучать бедный клиент.

Answer (score 13):

`sleep(1)` - это особый вид sleep. Он говорит планировщику потоков - поток, который вызвал его, свой квант времени отработал.

Дело в том, что для обеспечения мультизадачности, каждый поток получает свой квант времени на работу (обычно от 50мс на декстопе до 130 на серверных системах). Если потоки отрабатывают цикл за 10 мс, а потом ждут данные или делают активную синхронизацию (`while (get_var(xxx)) {/*do nothing*/}`, где get_var просто получает переменную, используя синхронизацию), то они конечно будут отставать по отношению к тем, которые более полно выбирают свой квант.  Случайным образом расставленные `sleep(1)` работу не ускорят, а замедлят (из-за накладных расходов на переключение контекста - а оно не дешевое).

Делайте выводы.

Comment: @KoVadim, т.е. допустим в потоке есть цикл, одна интерация которого - к примеру парсинг одной ссылки из интернета. И если поставить в конце каждой интерации Sleep(1), скорость выполнения потоков увеличится?

Comment: И да, и нет. Если у Вас там один поток, который качает файлы, то sleep скорее всего не ускорит ничего (тем более в такой задаче).

sleep поможет, если итерации мелкие (сильно меньше кванта). Но это костыль:)

Comment: Даже если каждая ссылка качается в своём потоке - ничего это не даст. Если, конечно, внутри самой качалки не предусмотрена отдача квантов, но это вряд ли.

Comment: @KoVadim,@klopp - спасибо.