# Метод System.Threading.Thread.Sleep делает задержку ровно на указанное время?

Tags: c#, datetime, sleep

Функция Sleep делает задержку ровно на указанное время?

Или микросекунду с лишнем от реального времени?

Каким образом работает задержка времени, это реальное время или такт работы процессора?

У меня происходит большие задержки, но из-за  `Console.WriteLine`, поэтому время задержки не определяется точно.

```
for (byte a = 0; a < 100; a++)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
    //Console.WriteLine(i);
    //Console.Write(DateTime.Now.Second);
    //Console.Write(" ");
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
}
```

Console.WriteLine:

192
466
479
487
501
514
517
519
522
524
525
529
531
533
535
537
539
541
543
546
549
551
553
555
557
559

```
var ar = new List<int>();
        for (byte a = 0; a < 100; a++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
            //Console.WriteLine(i);
            //Console.Write(DateTime.Now.Second);
            //Console.Write(" ");
            ar.Add(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        }
        foreach (var i in ar)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
```

299
303
305
307
309
311
313
315
317
319
330
332
334

Comment: Ну пишите в List, а не на экран, а на экран выводите вне цикла...

Comment: `Sleep` осуществляет приостановку на заданное кол-во миллисекунд.

Comment: а как эта приостановка происходит (как приостанавливается программа)?

Comment: почитайте тут а работе `Sleep(1)` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/316526/194837

Answer (score 8):

Почему происходит разница во времени? Немного теории о работе `Sleep`.

Поток может сообщить системе, что в течение некоторого времени его не нужно планировать на исполнение. Эта задача решается статическим методом `Sleep`.
После чего система забирает поток у планировщика **примерно на указанное время**. То есть если вы говорите системе, что метод хочет приостановить работу на `100 мс`, он будет приостановлен примерно на это время, **но возможно пробудет в состоянии покоя на несколько секунд меньше или больше**. Не забывайте, что **Windows не является операционной системой реального времени**. Поэтому поток, скорее всего, пробудится в указанное время, но по большому счету **время его пробуждения зависит от остальных происходящих в системе процессов**.

Если методу `Sleep` передать значение `-1` или `System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite` то в результате поток окажется заблокированным на неограниченное время. При этом он будет существовать, и вы в любой момент сможете восстановить его стек и ядро.

Если методу `Sleep` передать значение `0`  то это сообщит системе, что вызывающий поток освобождает ее от его исполнения и заставляет запланировать другой поток. Впрочем, система при отсутствии доступных для планирования потоков такого же или более высокого приоритета может снова запланировать исполнение потока.

Если методу `Sleep` передать значение `1`  это включает принудительное переключение контекста, и **Windows** погружает поток в спящее состояние **более чем на** `1 мс`, что обусловлено разрешением внутреннего системного таймера.

Answer (score 1):

По информации с [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout)
```

> Количество миллисекунд, на которое приостанавливается поток. Если
>   значение аргумента **millisecondsTimeout** равно нулю, поток
>   освобождает оставшуюся часть своего интервала времени для любого
>   потока с таким же приоритетом, готовым к выполнению. Если других
>   готовых к выполнению потоков с таким же приоритетом нет, выполнение
>   текущего потока не приостанавливается.

В комментарии указано:

> The system clock ticks at a specific rate called the clock resolution.
>   The actual timeout might not be exactly the specified timeout, because
>   the specified timeout will be adjusted to coincide with clock ticks.
>
> > Системные часы идут с определенной скоростью, называемой тактовым разрешением.
> >     Настоящий таймаут может не быть равным указанному таймауту, тк он будет увеличен для совпадения с тактовым разрешением

Таким образом, [указанное в аргументе кол-во миллисекунд будет округлено до ближайшего соответствующего числа тактов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms686298.aspx) (ticks)